# What is the proper way to do html buttons for submits, cancels, deletes, actions, etc.?

Tags: html, css, button

Is there a standard way to code HTML buttons? One way I've been doing some buttons for a long time is to turn links into block-style buttons. I found though, that when I need a submit button and a link-button to look the same, it is very difficult to style.

Also, if I want to follow a more RESTful design, I'll need to pass HTTP DELETE and things like that as well.

Is there a standard way to code all of these buttons and be able to style them all exactly the same way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there isn't a standard way.

However, if you need a button, just use a button. I think you'll also find it easier to style.

Comment: +1 Since I use JavaScript for most of my events (rather than relying on for example a standard submit button's event) I almost always just use <button>.

Comment: In the cases where I was using anchor tags for non-submit buttons, do I need to use javascript to turn them into links?

Comment: If you are using `<a>` tag, you already have a link. Just add `href` attribute

Comment: I am using the anchor tag and I am already using href... I know this ;) What I'm saying is that styling this anchor tag to look exactly the same as the submit button is very hard. If you put them side-by-side, you can see little minor differences between them.